# Combination of same delimiters in awk

Tags: regex, unix, awk

I have a String

```
1__2_3__4_5_6
```

I want to set '__'(2 underscore) as delimiter in AWK.

```
$1 should be 1
$2 should be 2_3
$3 should be 4_5_6
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set `__` as FS value. You could also pass a regex as  FS value.

```
$ echo '1__2_3__4_5_6' | awk -v FS="__" '{print $1}'
1
$ echo '1__2_3__4_5_6' | awk -v FS="__" '{print $2}'
2_3
$ echo '1__2_3__4_5_6' | awk -v FS="__" '{print $3}'
4_5_6
$ echo '1__2_3__4_5_6' | awk -v FS="_{2}" '{print $3}'
4_5_6
```

`_{2}` matches exactly two underscores.

Comment: hi Avinash, 
I am getting below error:
$ echo '1__2_3__4_5_6' | awk -v FS="__" '{print $1}'
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: try `awk 'BEGIN{FS="__"}{print $3}' file`

Comment: Correct answer but I can't help wondering why the OP didn't know that you can set FS. It's step 1 in learning awk. @Mahesh - that error message means you are using old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris). Do not use that awk. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (or nawk, but it's not as close to POSIX).

Comment: No syntax erorr,but i am not getting expected result
$ echo '1__2_3__4_5_6' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="__"} {print $2}'

$

Comment: Why `-v FS="__"` instead of `-F __`?

Comment: Darn - didn't even notice that. May as well mention that RE intervals `{2}` will only work in some versions of some awks too.

Comment: @Wintermute i think it's better to put the FS value(multiple chars) inside double quotes (ie, using -v param) because shell will treat some chars differently.

Comment: That's not a bad instinct (except I'd prefer single quotes unless I wanted to use shell variables), but you could still use `-F '__'` or `-F "__"`.